# git rebase через один коммит?

Tags: git, git-rebase

сливать и редактировать коммиты я умею, а как слить коммит через один привету пример:
у меня есть 3 коммита

```
редактирование настроек базы
создание класса юзер
создание базы
```

т.е. когда я настраивал базу я косякнул в настройках, потом создал класс юзер потом опомнился и отредактировал настройки, теперь как мне сделать так чтобы слить последний коммит в первый?

Comment: ну косякнули. Залили ещё один коммит и продолжайте разработку

Comment: git rebase -i или забить

Answer (score 3):

Вот пример:

```
$ git log --oneline
44d5bd8 (HEAD -> master) редактирование настроек базы
e5b7713 создание класса юзер
7cdff4a создание базы
37865e6 init
```

делаем `git rebase --interactive HEAD~3`, (нам нужно переписать 3 коммита, поэтому указываем `HEAD~3`) открывается редактор в котором есть такие строки:

```
pick 7cdff4a создание базы
pick e5b7713 создание класса юзер
pick 44d5bd8 редактирование настроек базы

# Rebase 37865e6..44d5bd8 onto 37865e6 (3 commands)
# ... краткая справка
```

меняем порядок коммитов и что с ними делать. Мы хотим в результате получить два коммита: создание базы и создание класса, при этом в первом должны быть включены правки из третьего коммита:

```
pick 7cdff4a создание базы
fixup 44d5bd8 редактирование настроек базы
pick e5b7713 создание класса юзер
```

сохраняем файл и выходим из редактора. Если второй и третий коммиты действительно никак не связаны, то в результате произойдёт успешный rebase:

```
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
$ git log --oneline
af6d9d1 (HEAD -> master) создание класса юзер
fdb3b29 создание базы
37865e6 init
```

Документация:

- [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)
- [ревизии](https://git-scm.com/docs/revisions)

Comment: а если второй и третий коммит оказались связанны?

Comment: @AlexMur тогда тоже можно позаморачиваться разгребя конфликты, хотя в этом случе кажется проще сделать софт ресет и собрать коммиты заново